# How can you add IP/Domain to which the android application should communicate to?

Tags: android

I have built an android application which will communicate with the spring boot server. Now, i need to provide the IP in the android application, of the PC on which the server app is running.

Now, Lets assume, Endpoint is http://127.0.0.1:8888/home

If the IP of the server is changed to 127.0.1.1. I need to build the APK again with the new base URL.

Now, my question is, how can i make setting of IP address(Servers) dynamic in the android. If the IP of the server is changed, then the domain in URL should change.

Can anyone help me out. How the IP is set at the android application level.

Its an internal application. So, purchasing of Public IP / DNS is out of scope.

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1:8888/home` If your app uses that url it tries to connect with a webserver running on the same device/emulator as the app itself. Where is your app running? Where is your server running?

Comment: Further: if your app is used on different places the server will have a different ip too mostly. The first thing you can do is let the user type in the ip.

Comment: `If the IP of the server is changed to 127.0.1.1. I` ? 127.0.0.1 is not the ip of the server but the loop back address of every device. Of every emulator. Further: if you are in a LAN every device has a local ip.

Comment: Hi @blackapps. Thanks for the response. Assume that the mobile application and the server is on the same network. In this case, i am hardcoding the IP address of the server in the mobile application. So, lets assume, i change the server(in the same network). Then, i have to change the IP address at the android application as well. Is there any way, i can configure this?

Comment: Never hardcode an ip. If you have more pc's then every day they can have a different ip already. Hardcoding brings nothing. Better let a client determine its own ip address. Say a client finds its own ip to be 192.168.2.14 one day. Then the client knows that the server has an ip of 192.168.2.### where ### can be 2-255 in principle but in practice it will be around the 14. So just make a loop where you try to connect to all possible ips. Set a small timeout value. The client will connect within a few seconds.